# Adding a Google Docs link to my desktop

Tags: lubuntu, lxde

How can I add a Google Docs link with a Google Docs icon to my Desktop?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu do you have? When I went to the Google Docs website on 13.10 it automatically asked me if I wanted that done

Comment: @Anake I ALSO HAVE 13.10 BUT HAVE LUBUNTU. HOW DID YOU DO THAT PLEASE TELL IN BRIEF

Comment: It will be something different in Lubuntu.. I literally went to the website, Ubuntu asked me do you want to install the web app for google docs, I said yes and now I have a launcher button

Comment: Please, don't use all caps, it's annoying online.

Comment: @Anake :/ What to do now?, its not asking me for install!

Comment: @Braiam oh sorry!

Comment: I don't use LXDE I can't help you. The only suggestion I can say is install (and use) unity, and that's not helpful

Comment: @Anake but i use lubuntu as my ram is 512mb. what to do? :/

Comment: I think LXDE doesn't support web apps. This is a feature of the Unity environment, not of Ubuntu itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a Google Chrome browser installed to your system, open it and click **Apps** on the bar at the bottom of the window, right-click on *Google Docs* and select *Create Shortcuts...* from the menu;

[image: snap1]

Check mark the location where you want the shortcuts, and click on <kbd>Create</kbd> button. And you should have a shortcut created at those places.
[image: snap2]

Answer (score 4):

Write a desktop file with the contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Google Drive
Type=Application
Icon=google-drive
Exec=x-www-browser "https://drive.google.com/#my-drive"
StartupWMClass=DriveGoogleCom
```

save it to `~/.local/share/applications/` with the name *GoogleDrive.desktop* (for example). Download the GDrive icon from [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/75/Google_Drive_Logo.svg), and save it to `~/.icons/` with the name *google-drive.svg*.

**Note:** If the directories `~/.icons/` or `~/.local/share/applications/` don't exist you should create them:

```
mkdir -pv ~/.{icons,local/share/applications}
```

I haven't used Lubuntu in a long time, but now the Google Drive/Docs/whatever launcher should appear on the application launcher (and I guess you could pin it to the panel or create a desktop shortcut).

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 16.04, but I wonder if it is possible through any GUI tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Chromium (or Chrome, I guess it will work as well there) simply open google docs, then open the (three-dot) menu, go to More tools and click on Create shortcut. It's as simple as that.